# Why the time format change when I used the expression binding in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

In my HTML page I wrote this:

```
<span>{{trans.dateCreated}}</span>
```

the time format is:

> 2017-01-09T17:55:22.000Z

but when I used:

```
<span ng-bind="trans.dateCreated"></span>
```

the format changed to:

> Mon Jan 09 2017 19:55:22 GMT+0200 (Egypt Standard Time)

I don't know why this happened, but I want the date to be just 9/1/2017 or 9 Jan 2017, I used this filter (with the expression)

```
myApp.filter('shortDate', function () {
    return function (dateStr) {
        console.log("dateStr::", dateStr)
        var n = dateStr.indexOf('T');
        return date.substring(0, n);
    }
});
```

but it doesn't work, the `dateStr` is not defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer to this js fiddle: [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9182/)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <span ng-bind="trans.dateCreated | date: 'dd MMM yyyy'"></span>
</div>
```